# Joomla 2.5.14 New User Details message

Tags: php, joomla

I have a fresh install of Joomla 2.5.14 and I'm trying to change the message that gets sent out when then administrator adds a new user.

I've looked in the administrator/language/en-GB/en-GB.com_users.ini but don't see where to make the change. I also use the Language Override extension to see if their was something I just wasn't seeing.

This is the text of the email that is being sent out. Just need to change it a little. Anyone got a solution?

```
Subject: New User Details
Date: 10/08/2013 10:19 pm
From: Vote for ****** <d******@i********.com>
To: sophie@iensemble.com

Hello D*****,


You have been added as a User to Vote for ****** by an Administrator.

This email contains your username and password to log in to http:/b*******.com/

Username: d******
Password: p*******


Please do not respond to this message as it is automatically generated and is for         information purposes only.
```

Comment: This didn't work either:

language/en-GB/en-GB.com_users.ini 

COM_USER_ACTAVATED_BY_ADMIN_EMAIL_BODY

Answer (score 3):

I don't recommend editing the core language files as the could be overwritten by any future updates (like the one coming down the track).

You can override the language string using the Language Manager overrides you just have to be in the right section, front-end or "Site", backend or "Administrator" of the Language Override Manager.

If you can't find the constant `PLG_USER_JOOMLA_NEW_USER_EMAIL_BODY` it's probably because you were in the ***Site***" view while that string belongs to the ***Administrator*** view.  To change views use the pop-up menu in the right side corner of the Language Overrides filter bar:

[image: Language Overrides — Site/Administrator selection menu]

and select the area you want to create/search for an override.

Note you have to do this ***before*** clicking on the **New** button in the Toolbar.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so found where to edit it and you can't search for it using the Language Override extension but you can edit it via

**administrator/language/en-GB/en-GB.plg_user_joomla.ini**

```
PLG_USER_JOOMLA_NEW_USER_EMAIL_BODY
```

Hope this helps someone.

Comment: You can use the language override, see my answer.