# Joomla, Filezilla, Contact, changing automatic answer

Tags: ajax, joomla, contact-form

I have a problem with my website. I made the lines where my problem lays thick(bottom). Here it is:

```
"               **result = '<p style="color:white;"><?php echo** JText::_('VG_SK_CONTACT_SUCCESS'); ?></p>';            }           else            {
                **result = '<p style="color:white;"><?php echo** 
"
```

If I write between >< "Thank you for..." then it says in the automatic answer "Thank you for..." and there is another sentence which is maybe called by a function. I don't know very well programming, so can someone tell me maybe where I could find this data file, where I can change the automatic answer.

```
//CODE    

// no direct access defined('_JEXEC') or die;
       //library jimport('joomla.application.module.helper');

//vars //$class_sfx = htmlspecialchars($params->get('moduleclass_sfx')); $c_emailto = explode( '@', $params->get('emailto') ); $c_justdata = $params->get('justdata'); $c_justsocial = $params->get('justsocial');

echo '<div class="contactform"> <span class="error"></span> <span class="error"></span> <span class="error"></span> <span class="error"></span>
        <form id="contactForm" method="post" action="">
          <input type="hidden" name="emailto1" value="' . $c_emailto[0] . '" />
          <input type="hidden" name="emailto2" value="' . $c_emailto[1] . '" />
          <input type="text"  name="contactName" id="contactName" class="requiredField" value="" placeholder="' . JText::_('VG_SK_CONTACT_NAME') . '" />
          <input type="text" name="email" id="email" value="" class="requiredField email" placeholder="' . JText::_('VG_SK_CONTACT_EMAIL') . '" />
          <textarea class="requiredField" name="comments" id="comments" placeholder="' . JText::_('VG_SK_CONTACT_MESSAGE') . '"></textarea>
          <input type="hidden" name="submitted" id="submitted" value="true" />
          <div class="clearfix"></div>
          <button type="submit" name="submit" id="submitMsg" class="large_btn contact-btn">' . JText::_('VG_SK_CONTACT_SUBMIT') . '</button>
        </form>         <div id="note"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="contactinfo">
        ' . $c_justdata . '         ' . $c_justsocial . '
      </div>'; ?>

<script> // mail-form jQuery(document).ready(function($){   $("#contactForm").submit(function(){    var str = $(this).serialize();

    $.ajax({        type: "POST",       url: "<?php echo JURI::base(); ?>modules/mod_circle_contact/ajax/send.php",         data: str,      success: function(msg){
                $("#note").ajaxComplete(function(event, request, settings){             if(msg == 'OK')             {
                **result = '<p style="color:white;"><?php echo** JText::_('VG_SK_CONTACT_SUCCESS'); ?></p>';            }           else            {
                **result = '<p style="color:white;"><?php echo** JText::_('VG_SK_CONTACT_FORGOT'); ?></p>';             }

            $(this).html(result).fadeIn("slow");            $(this).html(result);

            });             //alert(msg);

        }

    }); return false; }); }); </script>

//CODE
```

Thank you, greetings

Comment: Which extension are you using for the contact form?

Comment: you mean jQuery, Ajax?

Comment: or what you mean with extensions?

Comment: I mean is this native joomla code or a component? See [extensions](http://extensions.joomla.org). If you want to change the strings that appear you should change the strings inside the `JText::_('VG_SK_CONTACT_FORGOT');` that is the `VG_SK_CONTACT_FORGOT` see this answer if it helps you: [Customize text](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20927963/joomla-customize-text-in-user-menu/20929310#20929310)

Comment: Thank you very much! I found the Filezilla Data ( en-GB.tpl_vg_grettla.ini ). And I have this new problem: I need to translate to german and it says on the website in the answer sentence ? on the hash instead of the umlauts: ä,ö,... ? How can I show also these letters.

Comment: Okay I got it!!! Now I am happy. Thanks, you can close the topic!

Comment: You should accept the answer to close the question.

Answer (score 0):

You should change the strings inside the `JText::_('VG_SK_CONTACT_FORGOT');` that is the `VG_SK_CONTACT_FORGOT` inside `en-GB.tpl_vg_grettla.ini` see this relevant answer: [Customize Joomla Text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20927963/joomla-customize-text-in-user-menu/20929310#20929310)